# Laravel Echo not subscribing to pusher channel

Tags: laravel, pusher, laravel-echo

I am not able to listen for a notification in a private channel. When I try to connect to the channel I can see in the pusher debug console that a connection is attempted but then it does not say subscribed. If I try to log the channel to the console it says `subscriptionPending: true`.

I am using the following code:

```
window.Echo.private(`App.Models.User.User.${Laravel.userId}`).notification((notification) => {
  console.log(notification);
})
```

I have not tried a `.listen` method after the `.private` method as I am listening for a notification to be emitted from Laravel.

Here is the contents of my channels.php file for authenticating the user

````php
Broadcast::channel('App.Models.User.User.{id}', function ($user, $id) {
    return (int) $user->id === (int) $id;
});```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was subscribing to the wrong channel, forgot my `User` model was in a directory called `Users` not `User`